# Add partitions for Kafka topic dynamically using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I was able to inspect particular topic for its partitions:

```
public  void addPartitionIfNotExists(int partitionId){
    Map<String, TopicDescription> games = kafkaAdmin.describeTopics("games");
    TopicDescription gamesTopicDescription = games.get("games");
    List<TopicPartitionInfo> partitionsInfo = gamesTopicDescription.partitions();
    boolean partitionIdExists = partitionsInfo.stream().anyMatch(partitionInfo -> partitionInfo.partition() == partitionId);
    if (!partitionIdExists){
        //missing part
    }
}
```

But I haven't been able to add new partition to a already existing topic during runtime. Don't know if that is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `KafkaAdminOperations` Javadocs for more info:

```
/**
 * Create topics if they don't exist or increase the number of partitions if needed.
 * @param topics the topics.
 */
void createOrModifyTopics(NewTopic... topics);
```

Not sure in your logic around `partitionIdExists` though, since the partition in the Kafka topic is just an index number. So, if there is partition `3`, it doesn't mean that there is no partitions `1` or `2`. Therefore a `NewTopic` API is just that simple as `numPartitions`. Nothing more.

Technically, what you are asking is just covered by that `createOrModifyTopics()` and that's it: you don't need to check for topics yourself.